# Kafka and timestamp ordering within a single topic partition for ingestion time

Tags: apache-kafka, timestamp

When exclusively reading messages from a single partition living in a Kafka topic where timestamps are configured for ingestion (broker) time, can I assume that all message retrieved from the partition will always be in strict timestamp order?

Comment: Can you show the configuration where you mean "configured for broker time"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258690/is-kafka-timestamp-order-corresponding-to-the-offset

Answer (score 1):

Kafka provides ordering guarantees while storing as well as retrieving messages i.e messages are stored & retrieved in the order they are sent.
Messages sent by a producer to a particular topic partition will be appended in the order they are sent. That is, if a record M1 is sent by the same producer as a record M2, and M1 is sent first, then M1 will have a lower offset(as well as lower Timestamp) than M2 and appear earlier in the log.

**A consumer instance sees records in the order they are stored in the log.**

However , *Kafka only provides a total order over records within a partition, not between different partitions in a topic.  But*, if you require a total order over records this can be achieved with a topic that has only one partition, though this will mean only one consumer process per consumer group(Not suggested). Using this analogy , if you have only 1 partition , then it's a yes for your use-case but if more partitions then again a yes for ordering on per partition basis but ordering can't be guaranteed across the topic(multiple partitions).

Comment: You mentioned offsets, but the question was asking about timestamp ordering.

Comment: The recordbatch  would be inserted in the broker in the same order  of batch and the ingestion time would also be coming in that order. An order symmetry is being created here(As per broker time stamp) . So same order would be guaranteed by consumer as well? Am I missing some thoughts?

Comment: The offset, order sure, but the timestamp settings are configurable https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.java#L31-L41

Comment: @cricket_007 :  Agreed !! , Relying on question's description, I presumed that proper configurations have been made to use the LogAppendTime :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was talking about a Kafka topic when it is explicitly configured for log append time.

I'm assuming that since the broker determines the timestamp and the broker owns a particular partition that timestamps in that partition will reflect timestamp order.

Rephrasing the question, is this always true within a single partition configured for log append time:

```
timestamp x <= timestamp y
        where
 offset x < offset y
```

Thanks.