# Is Kafka timestamp order corresponding to the offset?

Tags: apache-kafka, timestamp, offset

We use kafka for our message queue,Our business required that message timestamp must with the same order with the offset, that means: if there are message m1 and message m2, and (m1.timestamp

Comment: Apache Flink works well for event time ordering, just in case... if you are open for exploring different tech stack.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on the timestamp type used, there are two types:

- `CreateTime` - timestamp is assigned when producer record is created, so before sending. There can be retries, so there is no guarantee that ordering is preserved.
- `LogAppendTime` - timestamp is assigned when record is appended to the log on the broker. In that case ordering per partition is preserved. Multiple messages might get the same timestamp assigned.

By default, `CreateTime` is used. To change this, set `log.message.timestamp.type` for broker or `message.timestamp.type` for particular topic.

Comment: Do you know if there are any implications when consuming a topic where the timestamp does not increment in step with the offset?